# Trying to make post request to spring controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring

I am trying to make a post request with jquery to a spring rest controller I have setup. This works perfectly fine with the get request, however the post request is giving me a 403 error in the console. Here is my simple code.

```js
     $("#testBtn").click(() => {
        $.post("/test").done((data) => {
            console.log(data);
        })
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And my controller

```
  @RestController
    public class LiveValidationController {
    @PostMapping("/test")
    public String checkEmail() {
       return "hello";
    }
}
```

Comment: Launch the page with the jQuery in it from a server - don't load it from the file manager. The address bar should say `http://` or `https://` and nothing else (like `file://`).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Attempting jquery post request to spring controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53028620/attempting-jquery-post-request-to-spring-controller)