# Attempting jquery post request to spring controller

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, spring

I am trying to make a post request with jquery to a spring rest controller I have setup. This works perfectly fine with the `$.get` request, however the post request is giving me a 403 error in the console. Is there any better way to handle this, or get it working at all?

```
$("#testBtn").click(() => {
    $.post("/test").done((data) => {
        console.log(data);
    })
});
```

My Controller:

```
@RestController
public class LiveValidationController {
    @PostMapping("/test")
    public String checkEmail() {
       return "hello";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

403 status = forbidden. 
You receive this error because you have CSRF protection enabled.

- Solution 1: send csrf token in your post from js
- Solution 2: disable csrf in the spring security configuration.

The csrf protection is usually enabled by default if you have a dependency to `spring-security` module